# Catch exception in loop head but not in loop body

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

What's the best way to catch exceptions which occur in the *loop header instead of the whole loop or body.

Take the following example

```py
for value in complex_generator(): # throws exceptions I might want to catch
    ... # do work here - but don't catch any exception
```

What I don't consider helpful is wrapping the whole loop in a try and except block like so:

```py
try:
    for value in complex_generator(): # throws exceptions I might want to catch
        ... # exceptions raised here will also be caught :(
except Exception:
   ... # handle exception here
```

Inspired from golang one might encapsulate the try-except-block and always return two elements:

```py
def wrapper(iterable):
    try:
        for value in iterable:
            yield value, None
    except Exception as e:
        yield None, e


for value, err in wrapper(complex_generator()):
    if err != None:
        ... # handle error
    else:
        ... # do work but don't catch any exception here
```

This however doesn't feel pythonic and a type checker would also require a additional check. Any ideas?

Comment: does the `complex_generator` has to generate during the loop? Is it possible to pre generate (with exception) or to run the generator twice (1st loop to find exceptions, second for actual computation)?

Comment: yes, it encapsulates network traffic (e. G. Grpc Stream)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two levels of errors: Those that the generator throws, and those that your worker code throws. I would use a nested `try`:

```
try:
    for value in complex_generator():
        try:
            # do work here
        except ValueError:
            # catch ValueError and keep going
        except OtherError:
            # catch OtherError and keep going

        # any other error breaks the loop
except ExpectedGeneratorError:
    # handle generator exception here
except:
    # handle more errors
```

You could extract the inner part into a worker function to keep things tidy.

Comment: Although not very short, it feels definitely pythonic!

Comment: @dummy When you extract the inner part into a separate function `def process(value_from_complex_generator)`, you can do a one-liner like this`yield from map(process, complex_generator())`.

Answer (score 0):

Get the generator first?

```py
try:
  cg = complex_generator()
except Exception as e:
  cg = [] # could alternatively have a success boolean here, and wrap the `for` loop below in an `if`
for value in cg:
  ...
```

Comment: The generator can still throw as you iterate it, so...

Comment: oh, then I don't think it's possible to not catch exceptions without having a try/except inside `complex_generator`, throwing a custom exception, and only catching custom exceptions in the try/except that goes around the for loop

Answer (score 0):

I still think @Tomalak's answer is the most pythonic way to solve this problem. However I want to share the solution I ended up using, because both the `complex_generator` as well as the loop body might raise the same exception.

```py
from typing import Iterable, Iterator, TypeVar


T = TypeVar("T")


def wrapper(iterable: Iterable[T]) -> Iterator[T | Exception]:
    try:
        for value in iterable:
            yield value
    except Exception as e:
        yield e


for value in wrapper(complex_generator()):
    if isinstance(value, Exception):
        handle_generator_error(value)
    else:
        try:
            process(value)
        except Exception as e:
            handle_loop_error(e)
```

Note: For more complex scenarios one might use `match` ([structural pattern matching](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-634-structural-pattern-matching)) and move the body error handling inside the `process` function.